# BottomNavigationView with AppCompat

Tags: java, android, layout, bottomnavigationview, appcompatactivity

dear developers!

I’m now learning to develop apps on java and i have just recently discovered that BottomNavigationView exists. Before this I actually had just buttons lined up at the bottom of layouts (shame). I faced such problem: almost all activities extend AppCompatActivity, but navigation view only works with fragments (sorry if I’m wrong). Can I somehow use it with AppCompat, or probably use another widget? Would be very grateful for the answer, especially if it would be open. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nowadays Android Mobile Apps are developed in Kotlin!, Consider learning it directly as soon as possible

Comment: @GianlucaVeschi is right. To start development its ok to work with java but try to move towards kotlin as soon as possible. As its very fast growing language plus also have safety features that are not handled by java. You can check [this](https://www.xenonstack.com/blog/kotlin-andriod/) link.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning, thanks for your suggestions, I realy appreciate it!

To use BottomNavigationView with AppCompat activities, besides code given by @AnantaRaha, I also used this in .java files:

```
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.dashboard:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            , Dashboard.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.home:
                    return true;
                case R.id.about:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            , Aboutt.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

overridePendingTransition helped to get rid of blinks and small delays that Intent cause when you are using it (Another activity now starts immediately) :D

Answer (score 0):

`BottomNavigationView` can be used in Activities or Fragments. [Details](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#using-bottom-navigation)

You can set it in xml like:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

And in your res/menu/my_navigation_items.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_navigation"
        android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
</menu>
```